# Convert multiform cURL request to C# post web request

Tags: c#, curl, openstreetmap

I have this multipart form POST request in Curl given by

`curl -u user:pass -H "Expect: " -F "file=@"C:\Users\Desktop\45.gpx -F description=test -F tags=xxxx -F visibility=xxxx http://www.openstreetmap/api/0.6/gpx/create`

I have been trying to convert this to C# but somehow i keep getting a bad request error 400.

```
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection reqparm = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
        reqparm.Add("description", "test");
        reqparm.Add("tags", "upload");
        reqparm.Add("visibility", "public");
        reqparm.Add("file", fileName);
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        try
        {
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

            //client.Headers.Add("description", "test");
            //client.Headers.Add("tags", "upload");
            //client.Headers.Add("visibility", "public");
            //client.Headers.Add("file", fileName);

            byte[] responsebytes = client.UploadValues(url, "POST",reqparm);
            string responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
            Console.WriteLine(responsebody);



        }



        catch (WebException ex)
        {


            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        }
    }
```

Comment: You can run a wireshark trace of a good working example and the code above to compare the results. I suspect but am not sure that the issue lay in the "Content Dispostion" Header sections not being as expected.

Comment: Hey thanks for your input!
I did this already and here is the result
Started POST "/api/0.6/gpx/create" for 10.0.24.93 at 2014-10-24 10:29:12 +0200 Processing by TraceController#api_create as */*
Parameters: {"file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000005c71c58 @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20141024-1817-1hzaioa>, @original_filename="45.gpx", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"45.gpx\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n">, "description"=>"test", "tags"=>"uploadtest", "visibility"=>"public"}

Comment: Here is mine:
Started POST "/api/0.6/gpx/create" for 10.0.24.93 at 2014-10-24 10:56:29 +0200 Processing by TraceController#api_create as HTML
Parameters: {"description"=>"test", "tags"=>"upload", "visibility"=>"public", "file"=>"c:/path/gpx_file.gpx"}

Comment: Please edit your question. Adding such content in a comment is not very readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you get stuck with similar issues,

heres how to write this particular request in C#

http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/multipart-form-post-in-c

Enjoy!